# How do I format code on my own website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, format, indentation

I'm using prettify for color coding but my code is still flat and not indented correctly, how do I format it so it looks similar to github gist or pastebin? (I'm aware you can embed from these sites but it doesn't look very professional).

Comment: is the code formatted before you use `prettify` on it? I'm pretty sure these tools just take what you give them and color code it.

Comment: No it's not, also I'm using my custom wordpress theme with a css reset, I don't know how to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is flat, you will need to rewrite it - as in github. Maybe you could even find an autoformatter, but it will be as language-dependent as the highlighter.

If your code is only displayed flat, you might need a `<pre>` tag around it or set the css property `white-space:pre` to the surrounding element.

Comment: This worked thanks, I already had put in some <pre> tags surrounding the <code> tags but wordpress had already flattened my code so I just had to simply re-paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use gist.github.com. It looks petty professorial. If still want only CSS and you are on ruby [CodeRay](https://github.com/rubychan/coderay).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/)'s automatic formatting might suit.

With their [formatting extension](http://codemirror.net/lib/util/formatting.js), you can just do:

```
editor.autoFormatRange(from, to);
```

[Here's a demo of it in action](http://codemirror.net/demo/formatting.html).

You'd also get the ability to edit your code snippets - and if you don't want that, you can turn it off with the [`editor.readOnly()`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_readOnly) function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do, your welcome to go about it differently:

1. I would write my code in an editor, (like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), because it's ultra awesome).
2. I would make sure my code was formatted the way I wanted.
3. I would highlight the area of code I wanted and copy it.
4. I would then switch to the "html" tab in my Wordpress post editor.
5. I would type out an opening and closing `<pre>` tag. If I were using prettify I would type in `<pre class="prettyprint"></pre>`
6. I would paste my code between the opening and closing `<pre>` tags I just created.

[image: Steps 4,5, and 6]